# Get continuous data from Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

In one of my projects, I have to get the data from SQL Server and display on the UI and it is a continuous process, the data keeps on changing in the table, so I have to get the data after every certain time interval (lets say 30 seconds)

I was thinking to implement a background worker within a timer which get the data from the server after every 30 seconds, but I was wondering what would be the best practice to implement this solution.

This seems to be a common operation, but I couldn't find any relevant queries for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good C#.NET Solution to manage frequent database polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378778/good-c-net-solution-to-manage-frequent-database-polling)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a background, with a task, with a thread, whatever you fancy.

Have a look at [Stephen cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/)'s blog for more on this.
Scot hanselman also shows different approaches [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx).

Oh, and this msdn article: [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article as well.